# Spring thymeleaf adding th:text into data-def-val

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I able to parse th:text value but I need to add that parsed value inside another html tag for jquery processing purpose.

**HTML code**

```
<div class="cal-tbl text-center pzero col-xs-3">
                                                        <br> <span>Calories</span></br>
                                                        <h4 id = "calories" data-def-val ="th:text=${food.calories}"> 309 </h4>
                                                    </div>
```

Comment: You forgot to ask a question

Comment: @gerrytan i wanted the th:text parsed values inside the data-def-val

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use

`th:attr="data-def-val=${food.calories}"`

this is generic way to populate non standard tag with dynamic data